# react native ios - no such file or directory: /xxx/appName/ios/RnDiffApp/

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have been building a react native app using android only.
Ive now managed to get hold of a mac so i can start testing app on ios.
I uploaded project to github from my windows computer....then downloaded to my mac.

Im trying to build app using Xcode....however Im getting the 2 errors below:

```
No such file or directory: /xxx/myAppName/ios/RnDiffApp/main.m
No such file or directory: /xxx/myAppName/ios/RnDiffApp/AppDelegate.m
```

Interesting thing is that I see no folder called `RnDiffApp` in path `/xxx/myAppName/ios/`.....however I do the see the 2 files mentioned at the following paths:

```
/xxx/myAppName/ios/myAppName/main.m
/xxx/myAppName/ios/myAppName/AppDelegate.m
```

...so in summary, the 2 "missing" files are indeed present....however they are in the folder path `/xxx/myAppName/ios/myAppName/`....instead of path `/xxx/myAppName/ios/RnDiffApp/`, which apparently is where build tool is looking for them

Although interestingly, the folder path structure looks different in Finder (see below)....to what is does in Xcode Project navigator (further below).  App is called xs

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the name `RNDiffApp` comes from `rn-diff-purge` repo. Xcode does not take the project files from file system, it takes the files from .xcodeproj file. At the start I would recommend you to delete RNDiffApp reference from the project and add your files references.

Step 1:
Delete RnDiffApp folder. Make sure you click on Remove References after.

[image]

Step 2:
Add your files to project.
Click on Add Files to "Your project" and select your project files folder. Make sure `Copy items if needed` and `Create groups` are checked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the `xs.xcworkspace` in xCode rather than the `xs.xcodeproj` file. The `xs.xcworkspace` will include your pod modules and should resolve the path issues.

Comment: I was already using the xs.xcworkspace file to open the project.  That is not the solution

Comment: @jamesmurphy Your screenshot shows that you have the `xcodeproj` file open. That's what threw me off.